# Excel Autofilter Criteria array loop

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, autofilter

I need to filter a column by dates.  I determine the number of dates needed, and then apply the filter.  Originally I figured there were only 2 cases, Tuesday thru Friday where you use the previous date.  And Monday where Friday, Saturday and Sunday are needed.

Then I realized that there might be a holiday on Friday or Monday, and it would require more dates...and there might be a midweek holiday, like Thanksgiving.  I then came up with this to cover the 4 most common possibilities:

```
  dPosting = dLast + 1 'dLast is the last Date used in the filter
  Select Case Date - dLast
    Case 2: 'Regular T - F (1 day)
      shFF.Range("A1", shFF.Cells(lMax, lCol)).AutoFilter Field:=cFind.Column, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(2, dPosting)
    Case 3: 'Midweek Holiday (2 days)
      shFF.Range("A1", shFF.Cells(lMax, lCol)).AutoFilter Field:=cFind.Column, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(2, dPosting, 2, dPosting + 1)
    Case 4: 'Regular Monday (3 days)
      shFF.Range("A1", shFF.Cells(lMax, lCol)).AutoFilter Field:=cFind.Column, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(2, dPosting, 2, dPosting + 1, 2, dPosting + 2)
    Case 5: 'After F or M Holiday (4 days)
      shFF.Range("A1", shFF.Cells(lMax, lCol)).AutoFilter Field:=cFind.Column, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(2, dPosting, 2, dPosting + 1, 2, dPosting + 2, 2, dPosting + 3)
    Case Else: 'Other
      MsgBox "Too many days since last run.  Please contact me", vbCritical, "Out of Scope"
  End Select
```

Then I figured, what if the person that runs this is out for a week for vacation...and threw in the `Case Else`.

Now I think that the easiest and cleanest way will be to simply determine the number of dates needed from the last date that was run `dLast` and Now.  Put that into an array and use that as the Criteria...but I can't figure out the syntax.

Checked these, but still but can't make it work:

- [AutoFilter Criteria Using Array (Error) - Too Large String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042181/autofilter-criteria-using-array-error-too-large-string)
- [How do I autofilter using an array for criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153818/how-do-i-autofilter-using-an-array-for-criteria)
- [How to transfer criteria from string array to autofilter. VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146042/how-to-transfer-criteria-from-string-array-to-autofilter-vba-excel)

This is my test code to play with the syntax and data sheet:

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim d As Date
Dim sArr(0 To 2) As String

  d = #4/25/2016#
  For i = 0 To 2
    sArr(i) = "2, """ & d + i & """"
  Next i
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$16643").AutoFilter Field:=17, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=sArr

End Sub
```

The macro recorder spits this out for using 3 dates:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$16643").AutoFilter Field:=17, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
Criteria2:=Array(2, "4/25/2016", 2, "4/26/2016", 2, "4/27/2016")
```

What am I missing??

Comment: You could have the public bank holidays in the sheet, then do something like dim r as range: set r=find(date,public holidays):if r is nothing, then not bank holiday through your dates, or use application.countif(public hols, date)   You could also try trapping the error adding each filter in turn, so if 01/01/16 isn't in the filter it will error, then move on to the next one.

Comment: I thought about that, but this is for a user that would then have to update that Holiday list possibly...and that would be a nightmare.  Plus, they still want to be able to check those dates regardless of holiday status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use something like this, and calculate the dates, dt1 and dt2, using Date - dLast, instead of the selects, and try

```
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= ">=" & dt1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & dt2
```

Comment: That worked for me.  I like this because I can also get rid of the Array.  The days will be consecutive, so this should work fine.  Thanks.